# How can I suppress keyboard popup on an iPad HTML5 app?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, html, ipad

I’ve written an HTML5 application for iPad. It has one input field. Every time a user comes to this page, the popup keyboard appears.

How can I suppress this default behavior within HTML5/JS context?

In my app, if you type in a login & password, it shows another screen (without page reload). But the keyboard still exists, and you have to manually hide it.

Comment: Hmm.. One of solution it's to make it disabled... Any others?

Comment: Perhaps, as in my case, because you have a jQuery date picker assigned to the field.  But disabling the field also disables the date picker.

Comment: In my app, if you typed login & password, it shows another screen (without page reload). But keyboard still exist... And you have to manually hide it...

Comment: @Rob: Assign datepicker to a hidden input or other visual non-form element and add a click event to a button. Make the click event trigger datepicker to show. If necessary, add a callback on the complete (not sure the real name) event to get the value returned so that you can display it in another visual HTML element (even a form element at this point).

Comment: Have you tried calling blur on all input,textarea in the form before submitting the form via ajax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand your description of your problem, it seems incomplete. Could I try re-stating it, to see if I understand correctly?

1. The user opens Safari on the iPad
2. The user types the address of your HTML5 app into Safari’s address bar, and taps the “Go” button
3. The user is taken to your app’s login page. They tap into the username field, and the popup keyboard appears.
4. They type in their username, switch to the password field, type in their password, and tap the “Go” button.
5. Your app loads some different content on the screen via JavaScript. The popup keyboard is still present.

If that’s the problem you’re having, it might be worth calling the `blur` function on your username and password fields before you load the content of the new page. That might make the keyboard go away.

If the HTML for these fields looked like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
```

Then the JavaScript would be:

```
document.getElementById('username').blur();
document.getElementById('password').blur();
```